# Missing tiles when Django application is hosted on an Apache server

Tags: openlayers-2, mapnik, geodjango, apache

I'm building a GIS application using Django as my web framework and OpenLayers to implement a slippy map interface. I was initially using the Django runserver for development and everything was working fine. However, I recently ported my app on an Apache server and I started seeing some missing tiles as below:

[image: missing tiles]

It's not always the same tile that is missing and usually there are two or three missing tiles. Sometimes, after refreshing the page several times the tiles appear properly. There are no missing tiles when I zoom in or out. Note that the page keeps on loading for an indefinite amount of time when I experience this issue.

I'm using a TMS layer to display the map using data from the GSHHS database.The map is being rendered via a Mapnik XML file which uses the GSHHS shapefile.

Unfortunately, at this point I'm unable to paste any code over here since I'm unable to login to SE from work. I'll try to post some code later. I have no idea as to what might be causing this problem. There is nothing helpful in the Apache and Django log files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you catch this issue on different browsers?

Comment: @drnextgis: I tested it on Chromium and Firefox. The only difference was that on Firefox it was failing more gracefully because the browser was timing out the request. Therefore, the page wasn't loading indefinite amount of time.

Comment: @drnextgis I just discovered that the missing tile reappears by doing a cache refresh (CTRL + SHIFT + R) in Firefox. However, this only works in Firefox.